# Show or hide content of a div based on value inside another div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'd like to show a message inside a div if the value inside another div is over a certain value. I can work that out but the value inside the other div will change depending on what the user has selected and then the required message doesn't appear or disappear each time this happens. I'm currently using:

```
if ($('#id1').val() < '25') {$('#id2').css('display','none');}
```

So #id2 is set to display as normal, but when a dropdown selection changes the value displayed inside #id1 to something less than 25 it needs to disappear and vice versa.

Any ideas? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You need to:

1. Bind event on `#id1`
2. Convert the selected `value` to integer
3. Compare this against integer `25`
4. Use `toggle()` to show/hide the div based on condition
5. Trigger `change` event on page load

Code:

```
$('#id1').on('change', function() {
    $('#id2').toggle(parseInt($(this).val().match(/\d+/)[0], 10) >= 25);
}).trigger('change');
```

```js
$('#id1').on('change', function() {
  $('#id2').toggle(parseInt($(this).val().match(/\d+/)[0], 10) >= 25);
}).trigger('change');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="id1">
  <option value="$0">0</option>
  <option value="£10">10</option>
  <option value="£25">25</option>
  <option value=£50>50</option>
  <option value=£100>100</option>
</select>
<br/>
<br/>
<div id="id2">This should show when greater than or equal to 25</div>
```

Comment: Sorry, you've lost me. Real novice at this. What's the sum at the end there? That didn't appear to even hide the div initially.

Comment: @Jerpl I've updated answer to work on page load. There's no sum, `>=` will check if the value is greater or equal to 25

Comment: I should point out that the value inside #id1 is a price and will change dependent on what's selected from options in a select box. So "option 1" would be £10, "option 2" would be £15, and so on. The message in #id2 only shows when the price (value) in #id1 is produced, and needs to update each time that value is changed.

Comment: @Jerpl Please check updated answer. Also, provide complete HTML

Comment: I'm afraid I can't show the full code as it's a shopping cart system. There are a number of options inside a select box, each item selected from that select box results in a price shown in a div (#id1) and I want to show a message in #id2 dependent on what value is produced in #id1. I've tried your code above but it doesn't work. It hides the message but it doesn't show again when the number produced in #id1 is higher than 25.

Comment: @indubitablee Am I right in thinking I cannot use 'change' if the text value is inside a div and not part of an input or select? Is that perhaps the problem? Like I said - I can get it to recognise the number displayed inside #id1 and display or not display the message in #id2 depending, but I really need it to change when the user selects something on the page that then changes the text value inside #id1. Apologies for being a complete noob with this.

Answer (score 0):

something like this?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#id1').on('change', function() {
    if (parseInt($(this).val()) >= 25) {
      $('#id2').show();
    } else {
      $('#id2').hide();
    }
  });
  // initialize div state
  $('#id1').trigger('change');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="id1">
  <option value=0>0</option>
  <option value=10>10</option>
  <option value=25>25</option>
  <option value=50>50</option>
  <option value=100>100</option>
</select>
<br/>
<br/>
<div id="id2">This should show when greater than or equal to 25</div>
```